# What is the recommended pattern for running a node function from an express view?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I need to run a node function after a button is pressed. What is the recommended pattern for this? Should I use a form submission to another endpoint or use jquery to try and run the function onclick?

myNodeApp.js

```
var wrapperFunction() = {
  my node code
}
module.exports = {
myNodeApp: wrapperFunction
};
```

express view

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: All the client can do is make requests to the server, e.g., Ajax, forms, etc.

Comment: How about you build an API that your client can send requests to?

Comment: ajax will ignore `session` unless u use `withCredentials` option.